# Unable to load credentials from system settings. AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kms, aws-credentials

I am new to AWS, And I have developed a Lambda function with to Encrypt and decrypt with the KmsClient.

And this is how i am building the KmsClient with aws reagion,

```
final KmsClient kmsClient = KmsClient.builder().region(awsRegion).build();
```

I am using the Envelope Encryption to encryption , so i am using the GenerateDataKeyRequest to generate and key for the plain text,

```
GenerateDataKeyRequest generateDataKeyRequest = GenerateDataKeyRequest.builder().keyId(arnKey).encryptionContext(encryptionContext).
keySpec(DataKeySpec.AES_256).build();
   
GenerateDataKeyResponse generateDataKeyResponse = kmsClient.generateDataKey(generateDataKeyRequest);
```

at the above line i am getting below exception:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId).
```

I tried to solve this by setting the environment variable , but still it did not work.

My kms key policy is looks like as follows :

```
    {
    "Id": "key-consolepolicy-3",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:root"
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow access for Key Administrators",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantListBasedDecryptARN-role-yq6d97v7",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantListBasedEncryptARN-role-y6nnbdp3",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/EnryptLambdaTest-role-1bz9t33s",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantListBasedEncryptDecryptARN13-role-fflntszk",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantBasedDecrypt-role-w176vn3b",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/lambda_for_apigateway-role-rm37oxr6",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/DecryptLmabdaTest-role-zmggdsbr",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/suchi13role"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Create*",
                "kms:Describe*",
                "kms:Enable*",
                "kms:List*",
                "kms:Put*",
                "kms:Update*",
                "kms:Revoke*",
                "kms:Disable*",
                "kms:Get*",
                "kms:Delete*",
                "kms:TagResource",
                "kms:UntagResource",
                "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
                "kms:CancelKeyDeletion"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantListBasedEncryptARN-role-y6nnbdp3",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantBasedEncryptDecryptARNEnvironmentVariable-role-2pwqzde3",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantListBasedEncryptDecryptARN-role-4qmx465k",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/EnryptLambdaTest-role-1bz9t33s",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantListBasedEncryptDecryptARN13-role-fflntszk",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantBasedDecrypt-role-w176vn3b",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/lambda_for_apigateway-role-rm37oxr6",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantListBasedEncryptDecryptARN-role-5p55uuig",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/DecryptLmabdaTest-role-zmggdsbr",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/suchi13role",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantListBasedEncryptARNb1808271-role-dh6l7e9p",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/EncryptDecrptFunction-role-0ouhuwpj",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantListBasedEncryptDecryptARN-role-oje1caln",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantBaseEncryptDecryptARN-role-ageva6cf",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantListBasedDecryptARN-role-yq6d97v7",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/EnvelopEncryptDecryptTenantBased-role-js8d5hln",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantListBasedEncryptDecryptARN-role-eowajg5x",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/EnvelopeBasedEncrypt-role-hgv79ytd",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantBasedEnvelopEncryptDecrypt-role-n4nn6tdj",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/EnvelopeBasedEncrypt-role-7jewd19s"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow attachment of persistent resources",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantListBasedEncryptARN-role-y6nnbdp3",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantBasedEncryptDecryptARNEnvironmentVariable-role-2pwqzde3",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantListBasedEncryptDecryptARN-role-4qmx465k",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/EnryptLambdaTest-role-1bz9t33s",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantListBasedEncryptDecryptARN13-role-fflntszk",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantBasedDecrypt-role-w176vn3b",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/lambda_for_apigateway-role-rm37oxr6",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantListBasedEncryptDecryptARN-role-5p55uuig",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/DecryptLmabdaTest-role-zmggdsbr",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/suchi13role",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantListBasedEncryptARNb1808271-role-dh6l7e9p",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/EncryptDecrptFunction-role-0ouhuwpj",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantListBasedEncryptDecryptARN-role-oje1caln",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantBaseEncryptDecryptARN-role-ageva6cf",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantListBasedDecryptARN-role-yq6d97v7",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/EnvelopEncryptDecryptTenantBased-role-js8d5hln",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantListBasedEncryptDecryptARN-role-eowajg5x",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/EnvelopeBasedEncrypt-role-hgv79ytd",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/TenantBasedEnvelopEncryptDecrypt-role-n4nn6tdj",
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/EnvelopeBasedEncrypt-role-7jewd19s"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:CreateGrant",
                "kms:ListGrants",
                "kms:RevokeGrant"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

any help would be much appreciated:

Thanks in advance ,
Pradeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using IAM keys, as you're using a Lambda function you should use the Lambda functions IAM role.

Ensure the Lambda role has the correct IAM permissions including the KMS permission for `GenerateDataKey`, `DescribeKey` and `Decrypt`. The recommended policy from Amazon is below.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "kms:DescribeKey",
      "kms:GenerateDataKey",
      "kms:Decrypt"
    ],
    "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:kms:*:111122223333:key/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

Finally if you get any issues with these permissions ensure that the KMS key grants allow access to the IAM role in its [key policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/control-access-overview.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response , Can you please tell me What IAM permission the lambda should have ? My current lambda function has AWSLambdaExecute and AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole , we are using the arn key to build the kmsclient which we cannot skip..

Comment: Have updated, I believe this is the permissions. If you get any issues with those permissions you many need to check the key policy for KMS.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have updated the kms key policy in the above post, can you please tell me where exactly i am missing the permissions?

Comment: Hmm, and this is running your Lambda in the console?

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for the response and really appreciate your help over here, And i have updated my current key policy of the kms, can you please tell me where exactly i should place the above permissions

Comment: The above permissions would be attached to the IAM role of your Lambda as a policy :)

Comment: No problem glad I could help with your problem :)